# Colleagues Ignoring me as I work Independently on my Schedule

Tags: work-environment, colleagues, mental-health, workplace-rhythm

Well, I have been to this new Job. It's been like around 5 months. The work atmosphere was the best which I ever experienced (I only worked in small companies for short periods of time due to some issues). I did not get the salary i asked for,but its okay. The thing is, everyone was good to me, cracking jokes and stuff. I work individually on a boring project, the client is very slow to respond.

Other members belong to a different team (same client). I only report to the client and the team lead who is working from home.

There is a stand-up call every day, even though I'm not part of the their project I need to attend the call and state what I have done.

The Team rapo was good and I went with them for outing and stuff. It was fine. 
The client gave a very good review to the management (told them that I was doing exceptional work).

---

Now things have changed, the Team have kind of become distant. Ignores me in standup calls, I only get chance to speak last. I have also stopped hanging out with them. Several times I mentioned that I was left out of the call and had to speak after this. The next day when I was ignored, I did not talk. After the call, they told me sorry .. oh you were missed ..blah blah.

I think the reason for these are the following

1. I come a bit late to the office, these guys needs to come early due to some learning lesson
2. I take longer lunch breaks

I'm stubborn idiot myself.
The Scrum Master might have thought that I would start to follow their schedule. The company does not have any issues with flexible timing. His lack of control over me might be the issue.

As I told earlier I'm a stubborn idiot; this clubbed with some personal issues  has started to get on my nerve. The job is easy, very boring. I go there and sleep sometimes. There is no challenge. Limited learning opportunities.

I kept coming late, the next day they pass the call to me. They have started recognising my presence in the call now, but I don't have casual conversations with them now nor hang out with them.
One day the HR asked me that why are you looking dull, I told her the job was boring. My Boss was there behind me, he heard it. I hope this wont cause issues. I need this job and I'm not looking to leave it. The client has plans to absorb me into his main team and he has plans for other projects. He did not want to let go off me for another project of the company.

How can I amend this situation? Kindly advice

Update -- > Its a Programming Job

Comment: The title says they're ignoring you but you said in the body "They have started recognising my presence in the call now" which one is it?  And what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What do you feel needs to be amended? What your boss could have heard? The situation with your colleagues? Life is complex and people sometimes are less friendly/merry than they used... perhaps your coworkers are under stress and thus have been a bit distant? ... please clarify as your whole post tells a story and it *seems* at the end you ask something completely unrelated (the boss overhearing)

Comment: Was that just a figure of speech when you said you sleep at work?   Or is it for real?    And why would you not adjust your schedule to the team?

Comment: @Keith Technically i do not belong to their team.

Comment: *The company does not have any issues with flexible timing.* - Is this meeting scheduled to start before you get to work?

Comment: I get that.   But you are working with them, and expecting them to treat you as if you are part of them.   If you want to be treated like one of the guys, act like one.   When in Rome, do as the Romans do.

Comment: @Keith lol.....

Comment: @BSMP mostly ....

Comment: Just what are you trying to accomplish?  Job security?  Better relationship with your teammates?  What are you trying to amend?

Comment: You really should work on these issues, what I hear is, you are unmotivated at work due to being bored and are sleeping on the job.  You really should not sleep on the job.

Answer (score 11):

Your actions and comments have probably signaled to the group that you are not interested, or invested in the job.   They probably assume you are planning to leave, or find your to be a bad egg and are distancing themselves from you so as to not be considered hanging with the bad egg.

You need to reengage with the work and team, stop coming in late, stop sleeping, and stop making negative comments about the job.  Get motivated and become the best employee they have.  They wont move a negative person up, or on to better projects.  They will move the best people they have up.

Comment: Actually many teammates are leaving.... They don't really care about my work.

Comment: And i don't work in their team and there is no professional engagement required.

Comment: Then why do you think your colleagues are behaving like that because of you? Based on your comment, if others are leaving I would say that this dissatisfaction you feel is more globally spread than you think.

Comment: Many of the teammates come late... i'm just late to attend the call..I always attend it.

Comment: @techno - If you don't work on their team, why are you going to their meetings, especially when you attend the meetings late?

Comment: @Ramhound it's a skype call... not a meeting as such.

Comment: @techno - I don't care if it's a phone call, in person, or video, you are showing up late to the meeting, and everyone involved knows that is the case.

Comment: @Ramhound okay.. I have started amending the situation from today.I have started reporting on time and started some casual talks..

Answer (score 1):

It's always possible you weren't left out due to malice. If your relationship with colleagues is important to you, then don't let scrum meetings sour that. Nurture your relationship with them by going to outings and engaging with them in conversations (again, if this aligns with your personal interests).

If you still get the sense that they are intentionally ostracizing you after putting more effort at work, you need to schedule a meeting with your manager, or even the scrum master to ask if there's any problems with the way you're working, and what you could do to improve.

However, if your relationship with that team isn't too important, and as you said, the client is very happy with your work, I wouldn't put too much time and energy into worrying about that.